# counting using java multi thread ,seems not working

Tags: java, multithreading

purpose:create 4 threads,in each thread a for loop will add 1 to a shared int variable for 10000 times.At the end the shared variable is expected to be 40000.I  used two ways to do that,and the result was not always 40000 every time i ran the code.i wonder what's wrong.

method 1 with synchronized:

```
  public class bbb {    
    int i=0;
    public void add() {
        synchronized(bbb.class){     
            i++;
            bbb.class.notifyAll();
            System.out.println(i);
            try {
                bbb.class.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            bbb b=new bbb();
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int i=0;
                for (; i < 10000; i++) {
                    b.add();
                }
            }
        },"A");

        Thread t2=new Thread(t1,"B");
        Thread t3=new Thread(t1,"C");
        Thread t4=new Thread(t1,"D");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}
```

method 2 with optimistic lock:

```
static volatile int value=0;
static void optimisticLock(int expected,int update){
    if(expected==value){    
        value=update;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+update);
    }else{
        optimisticLock(value, value+1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                optimisticLock(value, value+1);
            }
        }
    },"A");
    Thread t2=new Thread(t1,"B");
    Thread t3=new Thread(t1,"C");
    Thread t4=new Thread(t1,"D");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
}
```

Comment: Was the result 39996?

Comment: Why do you need `wait ` and `notify` there? did n't understand

Comment: I ran the program, the java process is stuck when it reached 39950+ number, probably there is some kind of deadlock. Not sure what you are trying to do with so much complications. This can be done a little simpler.

Comment: method 2 always gets me `40000`

Comment: this is much simpler with an `AtomicInteger`

Comment: When you have to use `wait()` and `notifyAll()` in your first method then add a timeout so you will not get an deadlock: `bbb.class.wait(1);` otherwise just as @javaguy said it's not needed

Comment: @Steve Smith in method two,most times it was 40000 or 3999,,,in method wo half of the results was 40000 and somrtimes could vary greatly from 40000

Comment: @javaguy   it's my first time to learn multi threads.So i used notify,wait to better understand.

Comment: `Thread t1 = new Thread(...); Thread t2=new Thread(t1)`.   That's EVIL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need `wait()` and `notify()` there which is causing the issue and it seems like you are confused. In general, `wait()` and `notify()` are used in producer/consumer problems (refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)) and in your code, you are simply trying to **control the access to an `int` variable from various threads for which you don't need `wait` and `notify`**.

You can refer the below code which meets your objective with Method1 above (runs 4 threads and prints values using synchronization), I have basically taken out the `wait()` and `notify()` calls.

```
public void add() {
     synchronized(Testing.class){     
          i++;
          System.out.println(i);
     }
}
```

Also, in your code, it makes more sense to use `synchronized(this)` because you are synchronizing on instance variable `i` (from `bbb` object).

---

The other point you might need to note that is, for your task (using `int` variable across threads), you can simply use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) API with which you can **avoid explicit synchronization** in your code.

---

Also, I suggest you refactor your code as shown below because **passing `thread1` object to `thread2` is really messy** and hard to understand (Also,  ensure Java naming conventions, class names start with Uppercase):

```
public class BBBThread implements Runnable {

    int i=0;
    public void add() {
        synchronized(this){     
            i++;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    @ooverride
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i < 10000; i++) {
            add();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BBBThread bbbObj =new BBBThread();
        Thread t1=new Thread(bbbObj,"A");
        Thread t2=new Thread(bbbObj, "B");
        Thread t3=new Thread(bbbObj, "C");
        Thread t4=new Thread(bbbObj, "D");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not using an AtomicNumber ?

Comment: Just adding that while you are commenting :-)

Comment: i wrote the codes you posted at first and it worked. And then i learned wait ,notify mechanism and i added it in my codes.   i wrote it for me to learn java so the codes might looking confusing since the code isn't desined to accomplish sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

[[ @javaguy's answer is spot on but there was a couple of things that were missing so I thought I'd do this for posterity. ]]

First off, you should use `AtomicInteger` which takes all of the by-hand synchronization away.  Your threads just need to do:

```
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
...
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
   i.incrementAndGet();
}
```

No synchronization necessary since the `AtomicInteger` wraps a `volatile int` field and has logic to properly handle concurrent updates.

> I used two ways to do that,and the result was not always 40000 every time i ran the code.i wonder what's wrong.

The reason why you never reach 40000 is that you have race conditions around your hand synchronization.  After 3 of the 4 threads have finished with their 10000 then the last thread running will call `wait()` but no one is there to notify it.  If you just remove your wait and notify then your code always works for me:

```
 synchronized(bbb.class) {
      // no wait/notify here
      i++;
      System.out.println(i);
 }
```

Couple of other comments:

- Never lock on a class like this.  It means that other threads can call notify and wait on that class and affect its internal operation.  If you need a `static` lock then create a `static` lock object:
     `private static final Object lockObject = new Object();`
- Be careful of doing `System.out.println(...)` in threaded programs because `System.out` is a `PrintStream` which is synchronized itself.  A better pattern would be to take a snapshot of `i` from within the `synchronized` and then print it outside.
- In general try to do *no* IO inside of a `synchronized` block for performance reasons.
- Classes should start with an uppercase letter so it should be `Bbb` or `ThreadedCounter`.
- As @javaguy mentions, you are passing a `Thread` into the constructor of another thread.  This works because `Thread` is a `Runnable` but it's a really bad pattern and very confusing.  You should do:

  ```
  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { ... };
  Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable, "A");
  Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable, "B");
  ...
  ```
- It would be better to create an instance of your class and pass it to each of the threads which then can lock on the `instance` of it:

  ```
  synchronized (this) {
      i++;
  }
  ...
  final Bbb bbb = new Bbb();
  Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
             bbb.add();
          }
      }
   }, "A");
  ```

But again, `AtomicInteger` and other concurrent classes in that package are your friend.